# wordpress,Aliexpress dropshipping plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, aliexpress

I'm trying to publish products from **aliexpress** to my website using **Aliexpress Dropship for WooCommerce** plugin. actually, it was working perfectly. But when I made the update a message keeps showing.

> Import failed. Too few arguments to function
> A2WL_ShippingMeta::__construct(), 1 passed in
> /home/vol11_2/epizy.com/epiz_28003847/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/ali2woo-lite/includes/classes/model/A2WL_Woocommerce.php
> on line 282 and at least 3 expected

what can I do can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the plugin yet? If not, it might be a good idea to do so: [AliExpress Dropshipping Support Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/ali2woo-lite/). The plugin was updated a few hours ago though, maybe the fixed the issue already?

Comment: No, I didn't contact him, I will try it now, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a bug in the Ali2Woo Lite. We've already fixed the issue and [uploaded the new version of the plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ali2woo-lite/) on wordpress.org.